# Help with my funky PHP loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach

Ok so i have this [page](http://dev.posnation.com/build_system/systemreview.php?id=35&step=13) and when viewed in firefox the proper results show up but when i look at it in chrome or safari it is way off. Could it be the funky php loop that i am using that makes it off in the browsers..Here is my code

I am generating a left and right array..seems like a hack to me

```
    $left = array();
    $right = array();
$finaltot=0.00;
 for($i=0;$i<count($steps);$i++)
{               
$sql="SELECT *  FROM configure_system WHERE EstimateID='".$_SESSION['ESTQUOTE']."' AND StepID=".($i+1) ;
$expstep=ExecuteGetRows($sql);


if ($i % 2 == 0) {
      $sql="SELECT SUM(TotalPrice) AS TOT FROM configure_system WHERE EstimateID='".$_SESSION['ESTQUOTE']."' AND StepID=".($i+1);
      $tots=ExecuteGetRows($sql);
    $left["Step"][$i][]  = $steps[$i];
    $left["expstep"][$i][]  = $expstep;
    $left["final_total"][$i][] = $tots[0]['TOT'];
    $finaltot+=$tots[0]['TOT'];
  } else {    
   $sql="SELECT SUM(TotalPrice) AS TOT FROM configure_system WHERE EstimateID='".$_SESSION['ESTQUOTE']."' AND StepID=".($i+1);
   $tots=ExecuteGetRows($sql);
    $right["Step"][$i][]  = $steps[$i];
    $right["expstep"][$i][]  = $expstep;
    $left["final_total"][$i][] = $tots[0]['TOT'];
    $finaltot+=$tots[0]['TOT'];

 }
```

then since the left array only has 0,2,4,6,8,10
and right has 1,3,5,7,9,11

so my loops are like this

```
<?php for($i=0;$i<count($left['Step']) * 2;$i++) { ?> 
      <?php $i++; ?>
<?php } ?>

<?php for($i=1;$i<count($right['Step'])* 2;$i++) { ?> 
      <?php $i++; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

So as you can see the code is a bit off and i think that maybe the problem with why safari and chrome are off...any suggestions

Comment: @Matt: Stupid question why you separate them in two array, to do some zebra styling? If yes CSS have better way to do that ...

Comment: The table on the right looks fine to me. It's the images outside the table that looks screwy.

Comment: no its not a stupid question ....i have a right and a left column and the odds in the array because of the products go on the right and the evens go in the left

Comment: @RageZ. Bit rude. It's totally reasonable to ask that question

Comment: @Ben: He's saying that *his* question is stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do not use [foreach](http://php.net/foreach) instead?

```
foreach ($right['Step'] as $i => $val) {
     // ...
}
```

Also you could get the same results with only one query:

```
  SELECT SUM(TotalPrice) AS TOT
    FROM configure_system
   WHERE EstimateID='".$_SESSION['ESTQUOTE']."'
GROUP BY StepID
```

Comment: Did you mean "SELECT *, SUM(TotalPrice)" ?

Comment: @Ben: yep. I just gave him a hint about groupping. His script blows my mind to even think how to rewrite in properly from scratch.